# How to Rewrite the URL

Tags: url-rewriting

Here I mentioned the url

```
http://localhost/wp/2016/?category_name=cricket
```

now i need to rearrange the url like

```
http://localhost/wp/cricket/2016.
```

here cricket is category name and 2016 is year.

Remove the ?Query String Variable not a value of the querystring in the wordpress URl.

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/?$/(.+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/$1/?category_name=$2[QSA,L]
```

But Not Working

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will generate rewrite rules internally once you have selected a permalink format. You can do so under Settings > Permalinks in your WordPress admin area. WordPress will attempt to write to your `.htaccess` file. If it can't, it will provide you with some rewrite code you can copy/paste into your `.htaccess` file.

Either way, WordPress transforms URLs into query arguments. If you want to change the way that WordPress interprets URLs and retrieves data to be displayed, you'll need to investigate the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this for array based.

```
add_action('init', 'category_rewrite');

function category_rewrite() {

        global $wp_rewrite;
        $my_URL = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
        // in my example i am testing http://localhost/news-events/2015
        // Let save the second value 
        $my_URL_PATH=explode('/',$my_URL);

        $my_CAT = Array ('news-events'=>'cricket');


        $rule = $my_URL_PATH[1].'/(\d+)/?$';
        $rewrite = 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&category_name='.$my_CAT[$my_URL_PATH[1]];
        add_rewrite_rule($rule,$rewrite,'top');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Comment: news-events is a page menu asssigned page. Ispossible to get an array for category ?

Comment: i think this will override

Comment: Please note, that `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` being called on every page load is very bad practice as it has to rebuild the rewrite rules every single time! Instead, flush the rules only once (eg. on plugin activation) or do it manually by saving the permalink options under settings / permalink (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php).

Comment: Following my previous comment: As a result, any rewrite rule where the regex is depending on the URL requested would not work. You would have to use something along the lines of `$rule='([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$'; $rewrite = 'index.php?year=$matches[2]&category_name=$matches[1]';` and leave away the `$my_URL`, `$my_URL_PATH` and ` $my_CAT` stuff

Answer (score -1):

Using the below code the following source url

```
http://localhost/cat/<catname>/<year>
```

will be converted to

```
http://localhost/index.php?year=<year>&category_name=<catname>
```

Paste the code in your there functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'category_rewrite');

function category_rewrite() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $rule = 'cat/(.+?)/(\d+)/?$';
        $rewrite = 'index.php?year=$matches[2]&category_name=$matches[1]';
        add_rewrite_rule($rule,$rewrite,'top');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

so where I was doing mistake.

- I was not flushing the rules
- the rewrite should be in single quotes, including the matches , the entire thing should go as a "**non compiled**" string, wordpress will compile it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42046/discussion-on-answer-by-suyash-jain-how-to-rewrite-the-url).

Comment: Please note, that `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` being called on every page load is very bad practice as it has to rebuild the rewrite rules every single time! Instead, flush the rules only once (eg. on plugin activation) or do it manually by saving the permalink options under settings / permalink (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php).

Comment: it's very bad practice to flush rewrite rules on the init hook, this will cause performance problems